# Can I save an array of NSMutableDictionary by using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: objective-c, ios

Assuming that I create a custom class to hold an array of **NSMutableDictionary**.

```
    @interface CustomStore : NSObject
{
    NSMutableArray *allDictionary;
}
```

Can I use archiveRootObject:toFile to save the list?

What if I want to retrieve a custom class from the dictionary.
Do I need to comfirm encodeObject:forKey: in the custom class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and yes.  Here's a decent tutorial:  http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php

Answer (score 0):

Your custom class will need to adhere to the NSCoding protocol.  It's as simple as implementing initWithCoder: and encodeWithCoder:.   Once you've got your custom class implementing the NSCoding protocol, you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

By using NSKeyArchiver, the objects want to store has to confirm implement with NSCoding.

```
@interface YouClassName : NSObject <NSCoding>
```

And Implement with

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
```

So after your custom class has implement above, then can save them successfully in the list.